# Properly handle multiple files input with Formik and React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik

I can't find a proper way of handling a multiple files input using Formik and React.

```
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";

const MyForm = () => {
  const handleOnSubmit = (actions) => {
    actions.setFieldValue("files", "");
  };

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ files: "" }} onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
      {({ values, handleSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field
            id="files"
            name="files"
            type="file"
            multiple
            value={values.files}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setFieldValue("files", Array.from(event.target.files));
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

If you pass `value={values.files}` you get an `InvalidStateError`:

> Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

If you pass `value={values.files ? undefined : ""}` works but you get the React warning:

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.

If you pass `value={undefined}` you don't get to control the input value (for emptying the file selection on form submit).

And if you pass `value=""` you don't get the name of the selected file (or the number of select files) when selecting files on the input.

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Check an example at [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-galileo-xdkxk?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useRef` to get reference to the file input and clear it like this.

```
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const fileRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ files: null }}
        onSubmit={console.log}
      >
        {({ setFieldValue, handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field
              innerRef={fileRef}
              name="files"
              type="file"
              multiple
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
      <button onClick={() => (fileRef.current.value = null)}>Clear</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working but I had ot add `value={undefined}` to avoid the `InvalidStateError` runtime error after selecting a file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your example working by setting `files` to `event.currentTarget.files` and using a `<input/>` instead of Formik's `<Field/>`.

```
import { Formik } from "formik";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ files: null }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {({ setFieldValue, handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              name="files"
              type="file"
              multiple
              onChange={(event) => {
                setFieldValue("files", event.currentTarget.files);
              }}
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check out a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-galois-i5usy?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I see. But this way, you can't reset the input valie to clear out the file selection.